# Verilog simulation gives x as output

Tags: verilog

I am trying to simulate the following circuit using veriwell. However, simulation results is giving me the value of each net as x. Since the circuit does not have any backward loop, I guess every net should have either 1 or 0 signals.

```
module dff (CK,Q,D);
input CK,D;
output Q;

  wire NM,NCK;
  wire NQ,M;

  nmos N7 (M,D,NCK);
  not P3 (NM,M);
  nmos N9 (NQ,NM,CK);
  not P5 (Q,NQ);
  not P1 (NCK,CK);

endmodule

module s27(clk, in1, in2, GO, HO, AO, BO, CO, DO, EO, FO, a1, a2, a3, a4, o1, o2);
input clk, in1, in2;
output GO, HO, AO, BO, CO, DO, EO, FO, a1, a2, a3, a4, o1, o2; 
wire AO, BO, CO, DO, EO, FO; 
wire a1, a2, a3, a4; 
wire o1, o2; 

  dff A(clk,AO,in1);
  dff B(clk,BO,in2);
  dff C(clk,CO,o1);
  dff D(clk,DO,a1);
  dff E(clk,EO,a2);
  dff F(clk,FO,o2);
  dff G(clk,GO,a3);
  dff H(clk,HO,a4);

  and AND2_1 (a1, AO, CO);
  and AND2_2 (a2, CO, BO);
  and AND2_3 (a3, AO, FO);
  and AND2_4 (a4, FO, BO);

  or OR2_1(o1, AO, BO);
  or OR2_2(o2, DO, EO);
endmodule
```

I am using the following testbench (generated using a script):

```
  `timescale 1ns/1ps

module testbench;

parameter sOutFileName = "beSimOut.txt";
parameter nVectorWidth = 3;
parameter nVectorSpace = 1000;
parameter nSimCycle = 10;

/* simulation memory */
reg [nVectorWidth - 1:0] mSimMemory [nVectorSpace - 1:0];

/* simulation vector */
reg [nVectorWidth - 1:0] vSimVector;

/* bench variables */
integer nOutFile, nIndex;

/* connection variable declarations */
wire clk, in1, in2, G0, H0, A0, B0, C0, D0, E0, F0, a1, a2, a3, a4, o1, o2;
/* drive inputs */
assign clk = vSimVector[2];
assign in1 = vSimVector[1];
assign in2 = vSimVector[0];

/* simulation memory population routine */
task populateSimulationMemory;
begin
    for (nIndex = 0; nIndex < nVectorSpace; nIndex = nIndex + 1)
        mSimMemory[nIndex] = { $random };
end
endtask

/* simulation */
initial
begin
    /* start monitoring */
    $monitor($time, ": clk = %b, in1 = %b, in2 = %b, GO = %b, HO = %b, AO = %b, BO = %b, CO = %b, DO = %b, EO = %b, FO = %b, a1 = %b, a2 = %b, a3 = %b, a4 = %b, o1 = %b, o2 = %b", clk, in1, in2, GO, HO, AO, BO, CO, DO, EO, FO, a1, a2, a3, a4, o1, o2);

    /* populate simulation memory */
    populateSimulationMemory;

    /* open dump file */
    nOutFile = $fopen(sOutFileName);
    if (nOutFile == 0)
    begin
        $display("Can't open %s file for dumping. Exiting ...", sOutFileName);
        $finish;
    end

    /* simulate inputs */
    for (nIndex = 0; nIndex < nVectorSpace; nIndex = nIndex + 1)
        #nSimCycle vSimVector = mSimMemory[nIndex];

    #1 $fclose(nOutFile);
    nOutFile = 0;
    $finish;
end

/* instantiation */
s27 inst (.clk(clk), .in1(in1), .in2(in2), .GO(GO), .HO(HO), .AO(AO), .BO(BO), .CO(CO), .DO(DO), .EO(EO), .FO(FO), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .a4(a4), .o1(o1), .o2(o2));

/* dump */
always @(clk or in1 or in2 or GO or HO or AO or BO or CO or DO or EO or FO or a1 or a2 or a3 or a4 or o1 or o2)
    if (nOutFile != 0)
        $fdisplay(nOutFile, $time, ": clk = %b, in1 = %b, in2 = %b, GO = %b, HO = %b, AO = %b, BO = %b, CO = %b, DO = %b, EO = %b, FO = %b, a1 = %b, a2 = %b, a3 = %b, a4 = %b, o1 = %b, o2 = %b", clk, in1, in2, GO, HO, AO, BO, CO, DO, EO, FO, a1, a2, a3, a4, o1, o2);

endmodule
```

Any ideas on why I am not getting the correct output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which nets specifically are `X`, your inputs, or internal nets? You're not resetting your flops, so they will be X on initialization, but if there's truly no loopback as you claim they should converge to a known state as the inputs propagate through.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is what I was expecting. But, none of the nets (other than the inputs) are converging to a specific value. All of them are giving the value x. The inputs (including clk) are all giving 0/1 as expected.

Comment: I guess just check your 'dff' then, and make sure the transistors are behaving correctly. You should be able to see which arc is not behaving correctly.

Comment: @Tim I have done that, and have even replaced the transistors by simple NOT gates, but it has not changed the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dff is not modeled correctly. With the current dff, M will float (high-Z) when CK is high.

dff should look like this:

```
not N1 (NCK,CK);
cmos C1 (M,D,NCK,CK);
cmos C2 (M,NNM,CK,NCK);
not N2 (NM,M);
not N3 (NNM,NM);
cmos C3 (NNQ,NNM,CK,NCK);
cmos C4 (NNQ,Q,NCK,CK);
not N3 (NQ,NNQ);
not N4 (Q,NQ);
```

or as nand gates:

```
nand DN1 (NM,D,CK);
nand DN2 (M,NM,CK);
nand DN3 (Q,NQ,NM);
nand ND4 (QN,Q,M);
```

or as behavioral:

```
always @(posedge CK)
  Q <= D;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try to compile your code with the VCS simulator, I get a compilation error:

> Identifier 'GO' has not been declared yet. If this error is not
>   expected,    please check if you have set `default_nettype to none.

In your testbench module, you declare a wire `G0` (the number zero), but then you use `GO` (capital letter O).  You should change the zeroes to letter O's.

I don't think this will completely solve your problem, but this was too complicated to fit in a Comment.